# How to call a Main activity method in another non activity class

Tags: java, android

Below is My Main activity with `ColorChange` method.I want to call this `Colorchange` method in `ImageColor` Class

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void ColorChange() {   // <----- Want to call this method in below class

     ImageView blue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     blue.setColorFilter(0xff000000);

     }
    }
```

And this is my class where i want to call the `ColorChange` method of `Mainactivity`.

```
    public class ImageColor {


       public void Imager() {
                 // Want to call my ColorChange method here
             MainActivity obj = new MainActivity();
             obj.ColorChange(); //<-------- Using mainactiviy object crashes my app.
     }
    }
```

I have already tried using `Mainactivity` as object it  crashes my app.I also cannot declare my `ColorChange` method `static` because it uses `findViewbyid`.Please let me know if there is any way to call Color change method in this Image Color Class.

Comment: where you need to call ImageColor class?

Comment: I want to call ColorChange in ImageColor and then use ImageColor to change the color of my imageview.This is a sample project where i am trying to understand how to call main activity method from other class

Comment: you cant do that as you can see that the view(ImageView) is only in MainActivity if you call the same class method from another activityClass your View will not find its reference and application crashes with an exception which may be nullObject

Comment: use interface to communicate with activity from non activity class.
create colorChange() in interface and get the instance of interface in non activity class and call that method.

Comment: yes thats exactly the error i get null exception...how can i solve this?

Comment: actually the way you are trying is not a good approach. below answer by AnkitaShah is a nice way to achieve. But depends what you actually supposed to do

Comment: can u please give me example of how to use interface?

Comment: @abdullah first make your requirement clear. Actually you are accessing an activity(View) object withing a method from an class which need your activity class object and if this is gonna to be called within that Activity class only then you are why are you creating a new class you can do that in same class only without creating a object.

Comment: issue is Your activity ImageView only :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. It will help you.

```
public class ImageColor {


   public void Imager(Activity activity) {
             // Want to call my ColorChange method here
         if(activity instance of MainActivity)
               ((MainActivity)activity).ColorChange(); //<-------- Using mainactiviy object crashes my app.
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity classes are created by Android. So the above method is not correct.

You have 2 ways to access the method in activity.

1 .  using a static method

```
public static void ColorChange() {   
 ImageView blue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
 blue.setColorFilter(0xff000000);
 }
}
```

2. Using a callback mechanism

   ```
   public interface ImageLoadedcallback{
       void onColorChanged(int color);
   }
   ```

And update

```
    public class ImageColor {
            public void Imager(ImageLoadedcallback callback) {
            callback.onColorChanged(color)
            }
    }
```

And In activity

```
public void ColorChange() { 
    new ImageLoader().Imager(new ImageLoadedcallback{
       @Override
       public void onImageLoaded(Color color){
             ImageView blue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
             blue.setColorFilter(0xff000000);
       });
 }
```

Comment: you cannot call findViewById within a static method

Comment: ha ha ha. make the view as global and initialize in oncreateView

Comment: I just given the logic . Dont copy paste just think before you copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

use interface to communicate with activity from non activity class. create colorChange() in interface and get the instance of interface in non activity class and call that method

```
class MainActivity {

    interface mInterface = new interface() {
        public void colorChange(){

        }

    }
}
```

pass mInterface to non activity class and call colorChange of interface when you want ..

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass activity as a parameter in `ImageColor` class

Then call your ColorChange() method by refference of Activity.

Like This-

```
public class ImageColor {

    Activity activity;

    public ImageColor(Activity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void Imager() 
    {
        if(activity instance of MainActivity)
            ((MainActivity)activity).ColorChange();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, make an Activity as a static variable can lead to Activity leak, so we must avoid doing that.
I suppose if the Activity where you create ImageColor object is MainActivity, you can pass MainActivity directly to achieve what you want.

```
public class ImageColor {

    public void Imager(MainActivity activity) {
        activity.ColorChange();
    }
}
```

If you called it from other class(not from MainActivity), you can always passing MainActivity to that other class object to be used for ImageColor object.

PS: Check about java naming convention too, it will help you to write a better code